# how to add a namespace in xaml so i can use a class called ViewModel in MainPage.cs?

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

It seems that this line is not enough this line xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chartsample">
it says ViewModel not found.  I read that to use xlmns:local because it's coming the solution/project file.... then we would use "clr-namespace:Chartsample" where Chartsample is the name of the project.  Now maybe perhaps it needs to be narrowed down? but how?

```
namespace Chartsample
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Now, let us define a simple data model that represents a data point in SfChart.
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Height { get; set; }
    }

    //Next, create a view model class and initialize a list of Person objects as shown below,
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Person> Data { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Data = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person { Name = "David", Height = 180 },
            new Person { Name = "Michael", Height = 170 },
            new Person { Name = "Steve", Height = 160 },
            new Person { Name = "Joel", Height = 182 }
        };
        }
    }
}
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Chartsample.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chartsample">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Comment: don't nest ViewModel inside of another class

Comment: So the naming was correct but it had trouble accessing it because it's inside another class which some of the post I've read didn't touch base on.  I didn't know that it can't be accessed if it's another class.  answer updated.

Comment: Hi, have you solved it ? I have shared the ways in answer , you can have a look at it when you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not too much understanding your question , if you need to bind a `ViewModel` to `Xaml` , there are two ways to bind it for `MainPage` .

As shared code of `ViewModel` ：

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Person> Data { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new List<Person>()
        {
        new Person { Name = "David", Height = 180 },
        new Person { Name = "Michael", Height = 170 },
        new Person { Name = "Steve", Height = 160 },
        new Person { Name = "Joel", Height = 182 }
        };
    }
 }
```

**First** , you can bind it in `MainPage.cs` as follow :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       ViewModel viewmodel = new ViewModel();
       BindingContext = viewmodel.Data; // Here bind the model to MainPage.cs , then can use it in Xmal of MainPage
   }
}
```

**Second** , you can bind it in Xaml as follow :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-App18; assembly=App18"
             x:Class="App18"
             Title="MainPage">
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:ViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <StackLayout BindingContext="Data">
    <Label Text="{Binding test}"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is a similar [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140031/how-to-setup-bindingcontext-in-xaml) for reference .

Comment: xmlns:viewModels="clr-App18; assembly=App18"-= so App18 is the name of the solution in xamarin.  is this ok by itself xmlns:viewModels="clr-App18?  what is this addtion for assembly=App18"?

Comment: @chemobrain Hi , You don't need to think much about it, assembly has no effect on your reference to `ViewModel` here, it only affects references to system class libraries. If you use ViewModel, just use `xmlns: viewModels = "clr-App18"`.

Comment: @chemobrain If answer be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time :)

Answer (score 0):

how to namespace it in xaml

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chartsample">  //"clr-namespace:nameofproject">
```

to accessed a class in xaml it needs to be on it's own not inside another class which in my .cs file it's in public partial class MainPage

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
    }  //this is missing in code above

    //class view model on it's own
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Person> Data { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Data = new List<Person>()
            {
            new Person { Name = "David", Height = 180 },
            new Person { Name = "Michael", Height = 170 },
            new Person { Name = "Steve", Height = 160 },
            new Person { Name = "Joel", Height = 182 }
            };
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

All needed other classes are added in the scope of the MainPage class. So that only, it can’t be accessed through using namespace Chartsample in XAML. Please find the modified code snippet to resolve the issue,

Modified Code Snippet [C#]:

```
namespace Chartsample
{
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
   }

    //Now, let us define a simple data model that represents a data point in SfChart.
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Height { get; set; }
    }

//Next, create a view model class and initialize a list of Person objects as shown below,
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Person> Data { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Data = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person { Name = "David", Height = 180 },
                new Person { Name = "Michael", Height = 170 },
                new Person { Name = "Steve", Height = 160 },
                new Person { Name = "Joel", Height = 182 }
            };
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how would you add namespace in xaml?

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/charts/getting-started#initialize-chart - please refer it